# Trying to count number of complaint, cause, corrections

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to create a query with the following fields, that counts the number of Complaints, causes, and corrections show up in the data.

My current error:  Select non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

I am very new to SQL queries, and am not sure what else I'm missing. All I've done is merged to queries, and seem to be missing something.

```
select L.Case_ID,
    L.Case_Line_ID,
    A.Dealer_ID,
    M.DealerCode,
    H.DealerName,
    substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,7) as CaseMonth,
    count(distinct L.Complaint) as Complaint,                 
    count(distinct C.Cause) as Cause,
    count(distinct C.Correction) as Correction
from     Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_LineItems L
join     Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_Cases A on L.Case_ID = A.Case_ID
join      Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Rpt_DecisivDealerMap M on A.Dealer_ID = M.DecisivDealerID
and cast(substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,10) as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') between                                                                 M.EffectiveStartDate and coalesce(M.EffectiveEndDate, cast('2099-12-31' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
join Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Rpt_DealerDirectoryHierarchy H on  M.DealerCode = H.DealerCode                                                              
join Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_LineItems_Clobs C on  C.Case_ID = L.Case_ID
and C.Case_Line_ID = L.Case_Line_ID
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Looking to get a table with the following data example:

Dealer ID, Dealer Code, Dealer Name, Case Month, Count of Case_ID, Count of Case_Line_ID, Count of Complaint, Count of Cause, Count of Correction

Answer (score 0):

You have six unaggregated columns:

```
select L.Case_ID,
       L.Case_Line_ID,
       A.Dealer_ID,
       M.DealerCode,
       H.DealerName,
       substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,7) as CaseMonth,
```

These should all be in the `group by`:

```
group by L.Case_ID, L.Case_Line_ID, A.Dealer_ID,
         M.DealerCode, H.DealerName,
         substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,7) as CaseMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon wrote, the GROUP BY list doesn't match your Select, you need to either remove both Case_ID & Case_Line_ID or aggregate them:

```
SELECT
    A.Dealer_ID,
    M.DealerCode,
    H.DealerName,
    Substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,7) AS CaseMonth,
    Count(L.Case_ID),      -- distinct ?
    Count(L.Case_Line_ID), -- distinct ?
    Count(DISTINCT L.Complaint) AS Complaint,                 
    Count(DISTINCT C.Cause) AS Cause,
    Count(DISTINCT C.Correction) AS Correction
FROM     Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_LineItems AS L
JOIN     Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_Cases AS A
  ON L.Case_ID = A.Case_ID
JOIN     Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Rpt_DecisivDealerMap AS M
  ON A.Dealer_ID = M.DecisivDealerID
 AND Cast(Substr(L.Estimate_Created_At,1,10) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN M.EffectiveStartDate AND Coalesce(M.EffectiveEndDate, DATE '2099-12-31')
JOIN Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Rpt_DealerDirectoryHierarchy AS H
  ON  M.DealerCode = H.DealerCode                                                              
JOIN Decisiv_Tables_Prod.Stg_Decisiv_LineItems_Clobs AS C
  ON  C.Case_ID = L.Case_ID
 AND C.Case_Line_ID = L.Case_Line_ID
GROUP BY 
    A.Dealer_ID,
    M.DealerCode,
    H.DealerName,
    CaseMonth
```

I simplified `cast('2099-12-31' as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to `DATE '2099-12-31'` and used the column names/aliases in Group By (recommended over 1,2,3,4 in production code).

As Distinct is quite expensive check if you actually need to add it to those counts.